# Is this algorithm O(log log n) complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, logarithm

In particular, I'm interested in finding the Theta complexity. I can see the algorithm is bounded by log(n) but I'm not sure how to proceed considering the problem size decreases *exponentially*.

```
i = n
j = 2
while (i >= 1)
    i = i/j
    j = 2j
```

Comment: You can just compute an explicit formula from the recurrence relation $T(n) = 1 + T(n/2)$ (which this program satisfies) and the master theorem. The theta complexity is exactly $log(N)$, since base case is $T(1) = 0$

Comment: Since the factor 'b' in T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n) isn't a constant for this algorithm, isn't it incorrect to use the master theorem? That is, b increases by a factor of 2 for each successive problem.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to answer your question is to look at the algorithm through the eyes of the logarithm (in my case the binary logarithm):

```
log i_0 = log n
log j_0 = 1
k = 0
while (log i_k >= 0) # as log increases monotonically
    log i_{k+1} = log i_k - log j_k
    log j_{k+1} = (log j_k) + 1
    k++
```

This way we see that `log i` decreases by `log j = k + 1` during every step.
Now when will we exit the loop?
This happens for
[image: 0 > log i_k = log n - (sum from m = 1 to k of m) = log n - k(k+1)/2]
The maximum number of steps is thus the smallest integer `k` such that
[image: k(k + 1) / 2 > log n]
 holds.
Asymptotically, this is equivalent to [image: k²/2 > log n], so your algorithm is in [image: Theta(sqrt(log n))]

Comment: Thank you for this neat method. It took a few reads to sink in but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote i(k) and j(k) the value of i and j at iteration k (so assume that i(1)=n and j(1)=2 ). We can easily prove by induction that j(k)=2^k and that

[image]

Knowing the above formula on i(k), you can compute an upper bound on the value of k that is needed in order to have i(k) <= 1 and you will obtain that the complexity is [image]